# TS2345 Error: Specifying Function Parameter Type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Why does the following code result in the error below?

**Code**:

```
const queryApi = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): Observable<ParsedData> => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
      axios(request).then(response => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
      }).catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
      })
     // Asserting value type causes error.
  }).pipe(map((value: AxiosResponse) => {
      const parser = new Parser(name);
      return parser.parse(value.data);
  }));
}
```

**Error Message**:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<AxiosResponse<any>, Observable<ParsedData>>' is not assignable to parameter of 'OperatorFunction<{}, Observable<ParsedData>'. Type '{}' is missing the following properties from  type 'AxiosResponse<any>': data, status, statusText, headers, config
```

If I add the type assertion `const response = value as AxiosResponse` the code compiles (see below).

**Alternative Code**:

```
const queryApi = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): Observable<ParsedData> => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
      axios(request).then(response => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
      }).catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
      })
  }).pipe(map(value => {
      const parser = new Parser(name);
      const response = value as AxiosResponse;
      return parser.parse(response.data);
  }));
}
```

**Definitions**:
[Axios definitions.](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts)

```
export interface AxiosRequestConfig {
  url?: string;
  method?: Method;
  baseURL?: string;
  transformRequest?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  transformResponse?: AxiosTransformer | AxiosTransformer[];
  headers?: any;
  params?: any;
  paramsSerializer?: (params: any) => string;
  data?: any;
  timeout?: number;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
  adapter?: AxiosAdapter;
  auth?: AxiosBasicCredentials;
  responseType?: ResponseType;
  xsrfCookieName?: string;
  xsrfHeaderName?: string;
  onUploadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  onDownloadProgress?: (progressEvent: any) => void;
  maxContentLength?: number;
  validateStatus?: (status: number) => boolean;
  maxRedirects?: number;
  socketPath?: string | null;
  httpAgent?: any;
  httpsAgent?: any;
  proxy?: AxiosProxyConfig | false;
  cancelToken?: CancelToken;
}

export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: any;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  request?: any;
}

export interface ParsedData {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: Could you paste definitions of AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse  and ParsedData

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak I added the definitions to the post.

Comment: thanks, and tell me witch line throws error

Comment: @PrzemyslawPietrzak The following line causes the error: `pipe(map((value: AxiosResponse) => ...`; the issue apparently is with asserting that `value` is of type `AxiosResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line `}).pipe(map((value: AxiosResponse) => {` you told TS that value is AxiosResponse type. You don't have to type callbacks in TS e.g. `[1,2,3].map(x => x + 1)` here TS knows that x is number. If you want to told TS that observable contains AxiosResponse by generic. `return new Observable<AxiosResponse>(observer => {` and remove type in map callback `).pipe(map((value) => {`.